# Values of differential 2-forms on $k$-dimensional planes

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, symplectic-geometry

I've found [this](https://www.vaia.com/en-us/textbooks/physics/mathematical-methods-of-classical-mechanics-2-edition/chapter-8/problem-9-let-pi1-and-pi2-be-two-k-dimensional-planes-in-sym/) demonstration (for [this](https://books.google.it/books?id=5OQlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=%22two%20k-dimensional%20planes%22%20%22carry%22%20symplectic&source=bl&ots=uaIo1SJ8N6&sig=ACfU3U0nH-TdidJYTy1zENwp8OFOaJ26Xw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ89eV-oyFAxUyX_EDHU-fAYcQ6AF6BAgfEAM#v=onepage&q=%22two%20k-dimensional%20planes%22%20%22carry%22%20symplectic&f=false) problem taken from "*Mathematical methods of Classical Mechanics*" by V. I. Arnol'd), and I could not decode this particular step:

> A $k$-dimensional plane can be uniquely identified by the value of its
> symplectic form. The symplectic form takes values in the intervals
> $[0,k]$

And so:

> there is a total of $[k+1]$ different symplectic forms for a k-dimensional
> plane in $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

What does the first sentence mean? Couldn't 2-forms be of whatever value?

Comment: Is that an AI generated answer? To me it seems like nonsense.

Comment: @ReiHenigman I had the same impression, but till some point it seemed plausible. In fact, it was the only approach I found for the problem

Comment: Regarding the question - I believe that it boils down to the rank of $\omega$ restricted to the $k$-dimensional plane. Try to choose bases for each plane, and play with it.

Comment: Thank you @ReiHenigman...I know it's a stress and I'm not claiming anything, just feel free to expand you comment into an answer if it is possible